# How can I find AVG of a group in Hive and compare against it

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, average

I'm not sure the title explains my problem very well, I'll detail it correctly here.

I have a table called 121_salaries which has columns empname, address, jobtitle, department and salary.

I want to find the average salary of each job title, then display the information of the employees who's salary is significantly higher than the rest, with that job title.

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT jobtitle, salary, AVG(salary) OVER() AS avgSal FROM 121_salaries) t WHERE salary > 1.5*avgSal;
```

This query gives me results but it averages the whole salary column instead of finding the average of each job title.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `partition by` in `avg` calculation so the average per jobtitle gets calculated. An empty `over()` clause calculates `avg` for all the values in a column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT jobtitle, salary, AVG(salary) OVER(PARTITION BY jobtitle) AS avgSal 
      FROM 121_salaries
     ) t 
WHERE salary > 1.5*avgSal
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by jobtitle to get the average salary for each jobtitle and then join on jobtitle and filter to get the empname that is greater than 1.5 times the avg salary for that jobtitle.

```
SELECT empname,jobtitle 
FROM 121_salaries a JOIN (     
SELECT jobtitle, AVG(salary) avg_salary 
FROM 121_salaries
GROUP BY jobtitle) b on a.jobtitle=b.jobtitle
WHERE a.salary > 1.5 * b.avg_salary
```